# How to get information of an Item in RecyclerView CardView Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a `RecyclerView` which is constructed by inflating `CardView` Layout. This is acheived by `onCreateViewHolder` method. I am passing a `ArrayList` of data to the `RecyclerView`.

My requirement is, on clicking the list item, I have to load a new page which shows the details of the item clicked. For this, I need to get the id of the item clicked which is not showed in the view. In the view I have only Name and email of the item.

Let's say, the ArrayList I am passing is of type `Person` and Person has member variables `id`,`name`,`email`,`education`,`location`. 
In the `RecyclerView` `onBindViewHolder`function, I am setting only `name` and `email`.

I need to get the id of the item, then only I can do a db command and get details of the particular person.

```
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerList);
rv.setAdapter(new NGOViewHolder(ArrayList()));
rv.addOnItemTouchListener( // and the click is handled
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),NGODetails.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ID", (IDOfTheItemClicked));

}));
```

I requirement is `IDOfTheItemClicked`, that is passing in the above

```
Intent(getActivity(),NGODetails.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ID", (IDOfTheItemClicked));
```

should be the id of the item that is in the `ArrayList` that I have passed initially.

How can I get to send the `id` of the `Person` object which is currently showing in the view, to the next screen, on clicking the list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set position for each item using setTag inside onCreateViewHolder method after that when you'll click then inside onclick you get a view reference from there, get that tag and convert to int( this will give you position of view)

onCreateViewHolder(............){
View view;
view.setTag(id, position);
view.setOnTouch or Onclick(View v){
String position = v.getTag(),toString();
// get your id using this position
}
}
```

Comment: But, View is an inbuild class and how can I add my own variable. Also, the `onBindViewHolder` is where the data from ArrayList is set to the view.

Comment: Yes, You can add any variable as tag. View class has it's function setTag(yourUniqueId, yourValue); There is no need in OnBindViewHolder to do anything. Only set in onCreateViewHolder method and set listener.

Comment: `public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        // get the single element from the main array

        // Set the values
        Person person = personList.get(i);
        
        viewHolder.mName.setText(person.get_name());
        viewHolder.mDesc.setText(person.getDescription());


    }`

Each person has an id. When creating view this id is not set. Only name and desc is set. I need to pass id along with each view that is getting created for all the persons in the list.

Comment: setTag like this:
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    viewHolder.mCardView.setTag(position);
}

Comment: Get click like this:
private class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
           public View mCardView;
 
           public myViewHolder(View view) {
               super(view);
               mCardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
 
               mCardView.setOnClickListener(this);
           } 

@Override 
public void onClick(View view) {
    String position = view.getTag().toString();  
    int pos = Integer.ParseInt(position);
    yourArrayList.get(pos).get.......;
}

Comment: What if I am using a search bar and filtering out certain views. Let's say I searched for person named `abc` and the list now shows only view for that person. In that case, value for `position` will be 1 but actually that person resides in 5th position in the arrayList. This will be a problem rite? Or
the in that case also `position` will be 5?

Comment: when you will search then your onBindViewHolder will be again called and will set corresponding position to tag as filtered view. When you will search then you will have a filtered arrrylist at your end that will be equal number of filtered view. Got it ? so you will get id from filtered arrylist.

Comment: OK got it. Lemme try. Thanks a lot for ur time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't change the order of the items in your adapter, simply call `yourArrayList.get(position).yourgetIDOfTheItemClickedMethod` in the onClick.

Comment: Well, this seems like a temporary fix. But, what if I am changing the order of the items? How can I get to send the id of the `Person` object which is currently showing in the view, to the next screen, on clicking the list item.

Comment: Are you changing the order of the items before or after setting the adapter? If before, there should be no issue, you are getting the shown person. But it is possible to add a "getPerson(int position)" method to your recyclerview adapter, which returns the shown person - called via `yourAdapter.getPerson(position)` in your Activity/Fragment.